# formatting the output using c

Tags: c, printf

i have multiple outputs that i need to print as columns side by side. is there any way to achieve this using C? something like the output of ls -a
i.e. i want to print the first column data, then the second and so on

Comment: It'd be easier to answer if you gave an example of the output you actually want to see.

Comment: the functions would be called in the order like bread() bwrite() pgsize() so on the outputs would be like 
bread //bread() 
1234
2345 
bwrite //bwrite() 
3456 
5678 
pgsize //pgsize() 
1024 now i want to print the output like 
bread bwrite pgsize 
1234  3456   1024 
2345  5678

Answer (score 6):

You can do this with format strings. 
See the [printf(3)](http://opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/fprintf.html) manpage for more info.

Comment: What an informative answer! I suppose you've been working on that all evening.

Comment: Haha.  Yes, I know it's short, but explaining printf is way better accomplished by the manpage than by anything I could write up here.  Besides, reading that manpage is a huge benefit to beginners.

Comment: The least you can do is provide a link to a nice manpage (I go with opengroup myself) and/or a simple code snippet that demonstrates the concept in question. Reading documentation is good, but the point of SO is to be a place with answers to questions, not a place with links to answers to questions.

Answer (score 5):

You'll want to specify field widths, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1838388/how-to-format-printf-statement-better-so-things-always-line-up) has a pretty good example of what you're looking for.

Answer (score 3):

EDIT (changing my whole answer):

For the formats that you get for free with printf (including some to do with length):
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/printf/

I would avoid using tabs to do this.  Tabs can be interpretted in different ways on different machines (2 spaces, 4 spaces, n spaces).  If this is a fun app just for you on your machine, tab away...but the following example is just as easy.

RIGHT JUSTIFY (8 is the width, s means string, | is just to show spacing):

`printf("|%8s|%8s|","try","this");`

would result in this:

```
|     try|    this|
```

LEFT JUSTIFY (- means left-justify, 8 is the width, s means string, > is just to show spacing):

`printf("%-8s%-8s>","try","this");`

would result in this:

```
try     this    >
```

Answer (score 2):

If you mean automatically calculating the number of columns and their widths and so on, you can't do this with `printf()` alone.  However, it's possible to add extra code to precompute the number and width of columns.  For instance, consider the [OpenBSD code for `ls`](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb/~checkout~/src/bin/ls/print.c?rev=1.26;content-type=text%2Fplain).

Comment: +1 for the suggestion but I think it is a bad example as it ignores multi-byte encodings as well as 0-2 width glyphs. Better getting that right on new code.

Comment: You make a good point, though it's tempting to point out that the question specifically asked for output like `ls -a`... where better to look than the code for `ls`?

Answer (score 1):

Let me make sure I understand; you have some code like

```
while (some_condition)
{
  bread();
  bwrite();
  pgsize();
}
```

and you want to display the outputs of those functions as

```
bread    bwrite    pgsize
1234     5678      1024
2345     6789      1024
```

Is that close to what you meant?

If so, then you have a couple of choices.  First, each function prints its output, but without a newline:

```
void bread()
{
  ...
  printf("%*.*d", field_width, precision, value);
  fflush(stdout)
  ...
}
```

where `field_width` is the minimum width of the column, `precision` indicates the minimum number of digits to be printed, and `value` is whatever your function is printing.  The `*` in the conversion specifier allows you to pass the width and precision as arguments to printf(), i.e.,

```
printf("%*.*f", 10, 2, 3.14159);
```

is the same as

```
printf("%10.2f", 3.14159);
```

The chief advantage of using the `*` flags in the conversion specifier means you can adjust your output format at runtime.  Note that `*` in a conversion specifier means something *completely different* in scanf().

Either the last function called or the caller will need to write a newline to the output stream.

Alternately, you can have each function return its value to the caller, and let the caller do all the output:

```
while (some_condition)
{
  int r = bread();
  int w = bwrite();
  int s = pgsize();
  printf("%*.*d%*.*d%*.*d\n", rwidth, rprec, r, wwidth, wprec, w, swidth, sprec, s);
}
```

where rwidth, rprec, etc., have all been declared and set elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

using `"\t"` and `"\n"`

Example:

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < m ; ++i)
{
  for(int j = 0; j < n ; ++j
 {
    printf("%d\t", a[i][j]);
 }
 printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: Tabs are a rather primitive and inaccurate way to control columns.